# How to receive a File in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using ZF2.

I am sending a file via a `HTML` form not generated by `Zend/Form`. Now I am trying to get that file as i would normally do with `$_FILES`. I tried the below PHP code but all I get in the `print_r is Array ( [upload] => bnk.csv )`

How do I get all the metadata such as temp_dir of that file???.... I am new to Zend so dont know if I am forced to create the form with `Zend/Form` which seems silly since I only have a file upload field thats a lot easier to manage directly from the view.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
            if($request->isPost()){
                $post= array_merge_recursive($request->getPost()->toArray(), $request->getFiles()->toArray());
                print_r($post);
            }


<form id="upload" method="post" action="bnk/upload/csv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="upload">Upload CSV File</label>
        <input type="file" name="upload" />
        <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  /* upload */
    $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
    $upload->setDestination("folder for upload");

    $upload->addValidator('Size',false, 1024 * 1024 * 5 ); //size limit
    $upload->addValidator('Extension',false,'zip,rar'); //extension limit

    $files = $upload->getFileInfo();

    foreach($files as $file=>$info){
        //if file is valid
        if($upload->isValid($file)){
            //confirm to upload
            $upload->receive($file);
        }
    }
```

I use Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http for uploading

Comment: modify to $upload = new Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); in ZF2?

Comment: When I do `$upload = new Http();

   print_r($upload->getFileInfo());` the array is empty somehow

Comment: try to print out $this->request->getFiles()->toArray(). Is it empty too?